# Container offset left in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two bootstrap containers, one inside header navbar of the page, the second below navbar. Inside each container there is some text. I want text that is in the navbar container to be shifted to the left by 15 px for all responsive breakpoints.

I tried to do this using a negative margin. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar px-0 navbar-light fixed-top bg-primary">
    <div class="container"><div style="margin-left: -15px;">Text1</div></div>
</nav>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">Text 2</div>
```

and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05tpydr7/6/) example.

This method works, but it has a serious bug. When the width of the browser decreases, text in header navbar starts to go beyond the screen. Is there any way to avoid this? Of course it is clear that I set up margin using `@media`, but I think this is not quite the right way.

Comment: I'm not seeing the text in the Navbar go beyon the screen. Can you post code that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the right way of nesting elements in Bootstrap you will end up with an aligned left side: `.row` will give you `-15px` to the left to counter the `15px` left padding on `.col-xx-xx`. What you could do is to add `15px` padding to other containers and let the `navbar` keep the normal bootstrap container `max-width`... That will keep the default `15px` padding on the `navbar` on mobile/tablet etc.

```
<nav class="navbar px-0 navbar-light fixed-top bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="container-inner">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/Kidkie/pen/JabyeB)

Comment: You're using padding for bottom container, but I wouldn't want it to be shifted. Offset I would like only for navbar container.

Comment: How do you want the navbar behave on smaller size screens? Should it realign with left side? If you make it offset -15px to the left it will touch the border of the mobile browser as the offset for Bootstrap container/cols/rows are 15px. You would have to realign on tablet and mobile... Or add padding to the main container to keep the possibility of offset...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navbar-fixed-top` instead of `fixed-top` for navbar section. In Bootstrap 4 adjust margin-left by using default css class `ml-1,ml-2,..` and padding `pl-1,pl-2` as follows.

[Ref Bootstrap 4 spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    Text 1        
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ml-4 mr-4">
     <p>Text 2</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Try your ans here: https://jsfiddle.net/testdesigner/aq9Laaew/193572/

Comment: I use container instead of container-fluid to make the content centered. In your case, text will be pressed to the left.